# Why do Narns like to live in surroundings with red-orange lighting?

Tags: babylon-5

For some reason, the Narns of Babylon 5 like to live in quarters with red-orange lighting. You can see that in G'Kar's quarters. Why this preference?

Comment: Planet Narn; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/babylon5/images/e/e3/Narnhomeworld01.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/350?cb=20080507180034

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing that addresses this directly (that I can find promptly), so I will answer with the most obvious speculation that Valorum has already provided visual for - **it's just like home.**

Every shot of Narn works the same way. We see G'kar receiving communications from other Narn on homeworld bathed in the same red light. Later we get outside shots of Narn, but mostly after it has been devastated by the Centauri, so it can't be fully relied on. Still, the red sky is prominent.

So either because it is familiar, or is more comfortable on their eyes, Narn light their spaces just like homeworld.

Comment: If wikia is anything to go by, the canonical reference for the Narn sun being a red giant, is [1]. This made the Narn eyes more sensitive to red and orange light. 

[1] "The Official Babylon 5 Magazine: Volume 1, Issue #3 (Nov 1997) - Page 26 (A Brief History of Narn)"

Comment: @Abulafia I don't suppose the text of that magazine is available online? A direct quote seems like it would definitively answer the question.

Comment: @Thunderforge No unfortunately I have not found it online.